# Control what ads go on my app

Tags: android, admob, ads

All- I was wondering if there is a way to control what ads go on my app when I am using AdMob or if I have no say at all. The only reason why I care is that I don't want users to come to the conclusion that my apps are say violent when they have ads for shooting games. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can select which kind of ads to show. All the settings are available in the AdMob control panel.

Comment: OK thanks a lot. I was not sure because I don't have an account yet. This question is part of my research into getting one.

Comment: No problem! There are quite a few things you to set, so I think you should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

on AdMob Sites & Apps page look at Manage Settings near your application , there you can choose what kind of ads types to show and also filter by text/URL